# Using blazor components outside of blazor app (eg. knockoutjs)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a migration project. I am the only  JS Developer on the team, and rest everyone are C# developers.
We are looking to migrate our existing application written in .Net MVC Knockoutjs.
Since most of out team is C# developers we are giving blazor a try.

Since the entire application rewrite is going to take time, we are hoping to rewrite the application piece by piece in form of blazor components and export those components one at a time to be reused in the existing knockoutjs application.

This will allow us to move over from knockout to blazor whilst continuing to support and maintain existing application.

I have looked at angular elements as one way, however, like I mentioned we want to give blazor a shot. I am curious as to if we could export blazor components into other applications and allow flow of data between them.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just replace each knockout page with a blazor one?  You can do these individually; they don't have to be converted all at once.

Comment: Uhmm I mean, lets say I create a new weather widget in Blazor and I wanna add that widget to existing knockout application as a component and from within knockout application, I should be able search for any city for weather..so data should flow between them.

Comment: I doubt there's a good path forward for doing that.  Since Blazor is C#, a lot of what it does is server-side, not client-side.

Comment: The biggest problem with this kind of integration is that Blazor cannot _see_ the changes of the DOM. Without this changes tracked by Blazor all the circuits cannot work as expected. Signalr updates or webassembly updates risk to be applied in an inconsistent environment. Technically speaking you can do it, but it's better to manage pages without mixing technologies.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, but Blazor WebAssembly can be purely browser based...  That said, I also doubt that there is a great path forward for this use-case, but mostly because Blazor has its own way of doing things that would likely interfere with this technique.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Yeah, knockout doesn't run in WebAssembly, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research and reading through number of microsoft docs, I was able to run an individual blazor component outside of blazor in a different framework (knockout mvc in my case),

To start with -  I initialized a new Blazor Webassmebly Project in Visual Studio targeting .net 5.0.

For simplicity sake lets take the counter component from the blazor bootstrap application.

Step - 1 Import the component you want to export as reusable component like this-
[image]

Step 2 - Modify your MainLayout.razor to load the component

[image]

Step 3 -  This is crucial step. In your Counter component you should add following lines of code, here we are going to set the reference of the component using DotNetObjectReference

inject
`@inherits LayoutComponentBase @inject IJSRuntime js`

In your component code section -

```
 private int currentCount = 0;

    private DotNetObjectReference<Counter> jsToDotNetBridgeReference;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        jsToDotNetBridgeReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("SetDotNetReference", jsToDotNetBridgeReference);
    }


    [JSInvokable]
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
```

[JSInvokable] Identifier helps the dotnet to recognize this function as something that be invoked from JavaScript.

Step - 4 Modify the Program.cs and index.html

Modify your index.html and change your div id to counter
[image]

Next modify your program.cs to look for counter id in html.
[image]

Step 5 - Set dotnetreference to javascript window object

In your index.html under script tag add the following script -

```
window.SetDotNetReference = function (pDotNetReference) {
        DotNetReference = pDotNetReference;
    }
```

That's all you have to do on the blazor webassembly app.

Step 6 -  Publish your blazor application to a folder. I use default location for now. Once published you will see following files and folders, and we are interested in _framework folder for most part.

[image]

Once publish is done, copy the _framework folder to the root of your other application like so -
[image]

Step 7 -  Go to your desired framework, for now I am gonna use knockout mvc application.

In your  layout.cshtml file add reference to the blazor library like so

```
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" autostart="false"></script>
```

Keeping `autostart = false` , is a great way to make sure your blazor component does not load when its not required.

Step 8 - Create BlazorInterop.js

In your framework project create a js file, I like to name it as BlazorInterop.js (could be anything ) and then reference it in your layout.cshtml like so

```
<script src="~/BlazorInterop.js?" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Inside BlazorInterop.js you will write functions that you want to execute from your host application inside your blazor app. Like this -

```
       IncrementCounter = function () {
    Blazor.start().then(()=> {
        DotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('IncrementCounter');
    })
   
}
```

Step 9 -  Create a div in layput.cshtml with `id=counter`

Create a div with id=counter, this will help blazor appp to recognize the div where it should plant the compoenent like so -

```
 <div id="counter"> 

    </div>
    <button type="button" onClick="IncrementCounter"> Increment Counter </button>
```

In order to see the blazor component right from the time page loads set `autostart=true` else if you want to load the component on demand I have added a button in host app to show that you can just call blazor functions if you want once the component is loaded.

In your blazor interop.js Blazor.start will start the blazor application and then `DotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync` will trigger the function inside blazor and  counter should increment.

Step 10 -  Add mime types in your mvc application in your web.config to serve static content like so -

```
 <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".dat"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/dat"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".br"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".br" mimeType="application/br"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".gz"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".gz" mimeType="application/gz"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/blat"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".pdb"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdb" mimeType="application/pdb"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".dll"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
    </staticContent>
```

And done !
Fire up you knockout application and you will be able to see the component.

This is basically what needs to happen for us to load blazor component in mvc knockout app, This methods should work for any other frameworks too however I am not sure for to add mime types to serve static content in lets say frameworks like angulr, react etc, but I am sure there must be some way. I have not researched on that.

There might be some errors one may run into and so I am leaving some documentation that I referred throughout this process.

Call .Net Methods from JS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Call JS Methods from .net

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0

How to correctly use blazor.start

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-6.0

This took a lot of time for me to put together, this specific workflow has worked for us and is scheduled for production release end of the month.

This has helped us to develop new features  for our application in a Blazor, resulting into moving ahead into a new technology without having to get new resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to attempt replacing all the javascript on an MVC page with a blazor component one at a time, you might try this process, it's worked for me.

Firstly, update or convert your MVC project to .Net 5.0.402.
It MAY work on an earlier version but I haven't tested it.

To your MVC solution, add a blazor web assembly app project.
This is the web assembly components project.

On the MVC view, at the place you wish to render your blazor component add:

```
@using myawesomewasmprojectnamespace.Pages

<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered"/>

<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

The '@using' declaration refers to the blazor web assembly app project, Pages directory.
The 'typeof(Counter)' type refers to the Counter.razor component in the default blazor web assembly app project, visual studio supplies.

I'm assuming you'll be able to write your own blazor component to swap with the Counter.razor component.

In the MVC project's _Layout.cshtml, or wherever the `<head>` tag of the MVC view is, include in the `<head>` tag for every page with a blazor component in it:

```
<base href="/"/>
```

Add the 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server' package to your MVC project.

Add a reference to the blazor web assembly app project, in your MVC Dependencies, project references.

In the MVC apps Startup.cs, 'public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)' method, add the following:

```
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
```

In the blazor web assembly app project, Program.cs file, comment out the following line to stop the application looking for a '`<div id="app"></div>`'

```
//builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
```

Finally, delete the favicon from the blazor web assembly app project's wwwroot directory as it will clash with the MVC one.

This then adds the 'Counter' component to your MVC view.

To add a different component to a different view, insert it with:

```
@using myawesomewasmprojectnamespace.Pages

<component type="typeof(Myawsomecomponentnamecompletelydifferentfromanymvccontrolleroractionname)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered"/>

<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

And start your blazor component with:

```
@page "/myawsomecomponentnamecompletelydifferentfromanymvccontrolleroractionname"
```

This took me ages to put together, please let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your response. I was able to run blazor components outside of in a completely different framework ! I jus saw this response.

Comment: No worries.
If nothing else, I can always look up my answer the next time I forgt how to do it.

I'd love to see your solution though.

Comment: Yes I am adding my solution as answer and then you can go through it ! :)

Comment: Awesome.
I might use it.
My answer is now giving me a whole shed of other problems.

Comment: I added my answer, feel free to go through, the mentioned workflow has worked greatly for us, and we are going live soon.

Comment: Explained in more more details here - https://medium.com/@kshitij.rangari92/reusable-blazor-components-outside-blazor-application-7067ec8c6e7f

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, available from .NET 6 on, is to make the Blazor component(s) available for instantiation from JavaScript by calling [`JSComponentConfigurationExtensions.RegisterForJavaScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.jscomponentconfigurationextensions.registerforjavascript).

I'm also in a situation where I want to migrate an existing JS application to Blazor step by step. However, it is an Angular application. To evaluate a possible solution, I created a demo migration project. See my [BlazorInAngularDemo github project](https://github.com/Xenoage/BlazorInAngularDemo) for the code and description and a [working demo](https://xenoage.github.io/BlazorInAngularDemo/#/). But as already said, its specifically for Angular. But maybe some ideas, especially in the README file, can help you anyway.

Comment: Hi, I was able to figure this out. I published a detailed instruction here - https://medium.com/@kshitij.rangari92/reusable-blazor-components-outside-blazor-application-7067ec8c6e7f